# How do I change read write permission in /var folder

Tags: ubuntu, root, chmod

I installed Apache in Ubuntu and it made folder `/var/www`.

Inside this folder I intend to create a php file, so that I can check if it is working or not, but I dont have permission to make new documents in there.

I tried `chmod 777 /var/www` but it says `chmod: changing permissions of ‘/var/www’: Operation not permitted`

How do I do this? Shall I be root and then do it? How to go about that. I don't know If I ever set my root password during installation of Ubuntu or not, because I dont really remember it right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sudo

> sudo chmod 777 /your location

When it prompts you for your password, type in the password of the account you logged in as.

do a "man sudo" for more info, but basically it elevates your permissions to root (if you use no other arguments).

Comment: Also doing a 777 on any directory, particularly your document root is not really secure, I would not recommend it on anything but the /tmp directory.

Comment: Even on `/tmp` it's not secure, not unless you also set the sticky bit (i.e. `chmod 1777`).

Answer (score 1):

You can also run:

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /var/www/html
```